# MethodType transformation for MethodHandle to accept Array Object paramters

Tags: java, invokedynamic, methodhandle

I want to adapt `String.startsWith` from `(String, String)boolean` to `(String[])boolean`, so that it can accepts `String[]` parameters, in which first two parameters will be mapped to the `(String, String)`. Therefore, I wrote below sample code:

```
MethodHandle test =MethodHandles.publicLookup().findVirtual(String.class, "startsWith", MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, String.class));
String[] myArgs = {"result", "data", "sijie"};
MethodHandle adapt = test.asSpreader(String[].class, 2);
System.out.println("Adapt... "+ adapt.type().toString());
System.out.println("Compare Result: "+ adapt.invokeExact(myArgs)); //Expect to return false.
```

The `MethodHandle` to `String.startsWith` is adapted to the adapt `boolean (String[])` at first. But the result shows the `adapt.invokeExact` failure.

```
Adapt... (String[])boolean
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: expected (String[])boolean but found (String[])Object
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.newWrongMethodTypeException(Invokers.java:349)
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.checkExactType(Invokers.java:360)
    at org.bytecode.generation.sample.App.main(App.java:78)
```

The new `(String[])` Object in the stacktrace is quite confusing. Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to fix it?

### Thanks

This problem can be abstract as: 
 How to adapt a `Methodhandle` that only accepts `(String, String)boolean` so that it can accepts `(String[])boolean` parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `invokeExact` call -- because `invokeExact` is signature polymorphic, you need to specify the return type explicitly using a cast:

```
System.out.println("Compare Result: "+ (boolean)adapt.invokeExact(myArgs));
```

That's what the stack trace is trying to tell you with `expected (String[])boolean but found (String[])Object` -- because you didn't have the cast to `boolean`, `javac` assumed the method handle would have type `(String[])Object`, but at runtime, it had type `(String[])boolean` instead.  (The order might be confusing.  Think of it like "given the method handle, what type do I expect to have been recorded at compile time for `invokeExact`?")

See also my answer to [Why can't I .invokeExact() here, even though the MethodType is OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278314/why-cant-i-invokeexact-here-even-though-the-methodtype-is-ok/27279268#27279268).  (That question involved subtyping and the resolution involved `asType` as well as adding a cast, but the information is similar.)

Answer (score 0):

Got solution after many retries.

```
MethodHandle guard =MethodHandles.publicLookup().findVirtual(String.class, "startsWith", MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, String.class));
String[] myArgs = {"result", "data", "sijie"};
guard.invokeWithArguments(Arrays.copyOfRange(myArgs, 0, guard.type().parameterCount()));
```